# How to change format of Vue3 Datepicker plugins?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

can someone help me?

i use Vue3 Datepicker. And i got value like this

```
Thu Jun 23 2022 17:14:00 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)
```

How to change that to this

```
Thu, 23 Jun 2022
```

Comment: https://vue3datepicker.com/api/props/#formatting

Comment: it just change placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date.
In your datepicker component you can send a prop `inputFormat="E..EEE, d LLL y"`